# javascript - string replacement, replace "^" with "" and "^^" with "^"

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

### Removing Temporary Escape Characters in JavaScript...

**Basic Example:**

I have the following string:

```
"[x^::^^y]"
```

And the output should be:

```
"[x::^y]"
```

Essentially, any occurrences of `^` that do not neighbor another `^` should be removed, and any occurences of `^^` should be replaced with `^`

**More Examples:**

```
.parse("[^^x:^y^:^^^^^^]") // output: "[^x:y:^^^]"
.parse("[^x:^^^^y^^^z]") // output: "[x:^^y^z]"
```

It will be part of the parsing script for a JSON alternative that I'm developing to hopefully reduce file sizes for internal storage files.

Comment: If you want a JSON alternative that's more compact, may I suggest [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts that doesn't really answer my question, but thanks for the suggestion. i'll look into it another time.

Comment: try replace("^","").replace("^^","^")

Comment: @ArunKumarMN that only works because each call only replaces the first occurrence of the search string...

Comment: This might work `str.replace(/\^+/g, m => m.length % 2 ? '' : '^')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One more idea: [Capture](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) one `^` of pairs to `$1` or don't capture the remaining and [replace with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/T5q9PC/2).

```js
function parse (s) {
  return s.replace(/(\^)\^|\^/g, '$1');
}

console.log(parse('[^x:^^^^y^^^z]'));
```

@PatrickRoberts comment: The pattern can be further reduced to: `\^(\^?)`

Comment: Nice find! `/(\^?)\^/g` also works with `$1` replacer, by the way.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Very nice, thank you! I noticed it could be slower, but swapped to `\^(\^?)` would even be the fastest.

Answer (score 6):

I would use [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with a replacer function like this:

```js
function parse (str) {
  return str.replace(/\^{1,2}/g, s => s.slice(1));
}

console.log(parse('[x^::^^y]'));
console.log(parse('[^^x:^y^:^^^^^^]'));
console.log(parse('[^x:^^^^y^^^z]'));
```

Comment: i'm a self-taught JS developer, been coding it for like 3 years... didn't even know that existed. i learn something new with every project i work on.

Answer (score 2):

Since a replace call will work on entire string, the two replaces, if executed one after another, will interfere with each other. Regardless of the order in which replaces are called this will always end up in wrong result.

The only way to solve this would be to use an intermediate state. For example if we were to use + as intermediate symbol it'd be something like:

1. Replace ^^ with +,
2. Fllowed by replace ^ with empty string,
3. Then, replace + with ^

Obviously + symbol might appear in the original string itself, so you'd need to select a better intermediate symbol which wouldn't appear in original string. It can very well be multi character or even a control character.

**EDIT**: The accepted answer to use the replacer function is much better approach for JS. I am leaving this answer here just in case someone stumbles upon this question with similar problem in some other language where replacer functions are not available.

Comment: It's technically possible to re-create replacer function technology in other languages.

Comment: Yeah, as long as a regex engine is there, it should be possible to create a utility method like that. Based on input size, might even be good idea. Just that in some languages it'd be cumbersome to do so. Especially the ones without lambda.

Comment: It seems that with lookbehind capability, it _is_ possible to perform two consecutive replacements. Even with that stipulation, your answer has been disproven.

Answer (score 2):

Excellent answers above !!

But another way it may be done is to use lookahead and lookbehind.

```js
function replace_carets(mystring) {
  return mystring
    .replace(/(?<!\^)(\^{2})*\^(?!\^)/g, "$1") //removes isolated ^ or last odd numbered ^
    .replace(/\^{2}/g, "^"); //replaces ^^ with ^
}
console.log(replace_carets("[x^::^^y]"));
console.log(replace_carets("[^^x:^y^:^^^^^^]"));
console.log(replace_carets("[^x:^^^^y^^^z]"));
```

Far from elegant but I challenged myself to do it alternatively so sharing with you.

Comment: Really? I see no error when I click "run code snippet". You may take a look here https://codepen.io/irfan/pen/gNmQBm

Comment: Code snippet works on Chrome but not on FF and Edge.

Comment: so it seems lookbehinds are not supported by browsers except for chrome. so not a recommended solution.

Comment: You can simplify your solution by removing the last odd numbered `^` from a group of 0 or more pairs (`*`) rather than a group of 1 or more (`+`): `function replace_carets(mystring) {
  return mystring
           .replace(/(?<!\^)(\^{2})*\^(?!\^)/g, '$1')    /* removes last odd numbered ^ */
           .replace(/\^{2}/g, '^');                      /* replaces ^^ with ^ */
}`